# Volume not used even though declared in docker compose // creating a directory at location in assumed volume is copyied to other location in the same

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to use multiple containers defined together in the following `docker-compose .yml` file

```
services:  
  mobile_app: 
    container_name: mobile_app  # optional
    build:
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # optional, default is Dockerfile in context
    ports:
      - 19000:19000 
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
    environment:
      - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      # - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true # Drains batterty, to be checked without usage, used for hot reload
      - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=<?????????> # TODO: USE YOUR IPV4 address without any port
      - MONGODB_CONNSTRING=mongodb://root:secret@mongodb # (experimental)
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: sihv
        target: /root/app/
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      # - code:/root/workspace/app # TODO: change to your workspace
  auth_server:
    container_name: auth_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.auth_server
    ports:
      - 1111:1111
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: sihv
        target: /root/servers/auth
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      # - code:/root/workspace/servers/auth
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=db
    volumes:
      - "C:\\Users\\Public\\db:/data/db" # mount is in the local machine
volumes:
  sihv:
    external: true
```

when i start it, it runs fine as
[image: running docker compose up]

but the sihv in docker dashboard is empty
[image: docker dashboard]

###### another

when I try to attach to multiple .devcontainer.jsons stored as in the following file structure
[image: file structure]

when I open multiple devcontainers seperately on different vscode windows and create a directory say "a", it's reflecting at these multiple locations in same volume

[image: pic4]

is there a way to resolve both of these issues..? and is there anything wrong with the declaration in docker compose file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing above docker-compose.yml to the one below, it works now

```
services:  
  mobile_app: 
    container_name: mobile_app  # optional
    build:
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # optional, default is Dockerfile in context
    ports:
      - 19000:19000 
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
    environment:
      - EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=<????????> # TODO: USE YOUR IPV4 address without any port
      - MONGODB_CONNSTRING=mongodb://root:secret@mongodb # (experimental)
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: sih_mobile_app
        target: /root/app/
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      # - code:/root/workspace/app # TODO: change to your workspace
  auth_server:
    container_name: auth_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.auth_server
    ports:
      - 1111:1111
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: sih_server_auth
        target: /root/servers/auth
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      # - code:/root/workspace/servers/auth
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=db
    volumes:
      - sih_mongodbv:/data/db # mount is in the local machine
  sih_flask1:
    container_name: sih_flask1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.flask1
    ports:
      - 8012:8012
    volumes:
      - sih_flask1:/tf
  sih_flask2:
    container_name: sih_flask2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.flask2
    ports:
      - 8016:8016
    volumes:
      - sih_flask2:/tf
volumes:
  sih_mobile_app:
    name: sih_mobile_app
  sih_server_auth:
    name: sih_server_auth
  sih_mongodbv:
    name: sih_mongodbv
  sih_flask1:
    name: sih_flask1
  sih_flask2:
    name: sih_flask2
```